# JPA EntityExistsException Duplicate entry when doing merge?

Tags: mysql, jpa, transactions, merge

Using JPA (OpenJPA) in a J2SE application I'm trying to update a table with the content of a List of Entries : adding new entries or replacing existing entries with what is in the List if they exist.

1) What is the best approach to do that?

For that I would like to perform several hundreds merge within the same transaction... (some of the entries in the List may be indentical with the same Id)

It seems to work fine when using HSQLDB, but when using MySQL as the database I'm getting this exception:
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException: Duplicate entry

2) any idea why?

The code is simple and something like this:

```
EntityManager em = emfactory.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

// update messages
for (Message msg : messages) {
  Entry e=new Entry(msg.getId(), msg.getText(),msg.getDate());
  em.merge(e);
}

em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

thanks

Comment: I'm guessing the exception is coming form the commit.  If so, you can try this to troubleshoot and find the msg that's causing the prob.  Move the commit in the for under the merge.  Surround the commit with a try/catch and set a breakpoint somewhere in the catch.  Also, what are the unique fields in your Message entity?

Answer (score 0):

Do a persist if the entity is unset, a merge otherwise...

This has worked for me with H2/HSQL/MySQL, the magic being in the em.contains() that checks to see if the entity is attached in your current transaction.

In the following example, e.id has a generation strategy of AUTO

```
if (e.getId() == null || e.getId() == 0) {
    em.persist(e);
    if (e.getId() == null || e.getId() == 0) {
        return null; //Or whatever you want to show that the persist failed
    }
} else {
    if (!em.contains(e)) {
        return em.merge(e);
    }
}
```